# Why is copy slower than move?

Tags: cp, mv

I had a big file that I'm moving about. The normal protocol in the lab is to copy it somewhere and then delete it.

I decided to change it to mv.

My question is, why is mv so much faster than cp?

To test it out I generated a file 2.7 GB in size.

```
time cp test.txt copy.txt
```

Took real   0m20.113s

```
time mv test.txt copy.txt
```

Took real   0m12.403s.

**TL;DR** mv was almost twice as fast as copy. Any explanations? Is this an expected result?

**EDIT-**

I decided to move/copy the folder to a destination other than the current folder.

```
time cp test.txt ../copy.txt
```

and

```
time mv test.txt ../copy.txt
```

This time cp took 9.238s and mv took only 0.297s. So not what some of the answers were suggesting.

**UPDATE**

The answers are right. When I tried to `mv` the file to a different disk on the same system, `mv` and `cp` took almost the same time.

Comment: There are a few variables here. If they source and target file systems are different, then `mv` can't be much faster than `cp`. But if they are the same, then `mv` entails just changing the _directory entry_ for the file, the contents remain unchanged. That should be faster than when one needs to copy the entire contents.

Comment: When you move the file in the same disk it is not actually moving. Its physical location will be there and just the indexes get update. Try moving to a different disk and you will get to know.

Comment: @terminalninja Do you mean scp?

Comment: No, I mean another disk. Like a different disk, If you are using a local machine, then an external disk perhaps or even a different partition in the same disk should be sufficient to see the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you mv a file on the same filesystem, the system just has to change directory entries to reflect your renaming. Data in the file is not even read.

(same filesystem means: same directory or same directory tree/same drive, provided that source and destination directories do not traverse symlinks leading to another filesystem of course!)

When you mv a file across file systems, it has the same effect as cp + rm: no speed gain (apart from the fact that you only run one command, and consistency is guaranteed: you don't have to check if cp succeeded to perform the rm)

(older versions of mv refused to move directories across filesystems, because they only did the renaming)

Be careful, it is not equivalent. `cp` overwrites destination by default, whereas `mv` will fail renaming a file/dir into an existing file/dir.